# jQuery Tools: How to close an overlay?

Tags: jquery, dialog, popup, overlay, jquery-tools

```
$("a[rel]").getOverlay().close();
$("a[rel]").close();
```

Both don't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[rel]").overlay({
            mask: '#3B5872',
            effect: 'apple',
            onBeforeLoad: function () {
                var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
            },
            onLoad: function () {
                $('.contentWrap form').submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("a[rel]").overlay().close();
                    hijack(this, update_employees, "html");
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function hijack(form, callback, format) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            dataType: format,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: callback
        });
    }

    function update_employees(result) {
        $("#gridcontainer").html(result);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

I use Chrome because the onLoad event seems not work correctly in FF.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("a[rel]").overlay().close();
```

For most of their scripting you call the original method, e.g. `.overlay()` then call [the method you want](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html#api) on that object.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for me. I edited my question. Maybe you know what is wrong there.

Comment: @Rookian - Are you getting a javascript error elsewhere? The api is pretty straight forward, I tested the above against several sites...looks like something else is interfering.

Comment: I have found the problem. I have more then one "a[rel]" element in my page. I have several edit buttons in a table and a create button that matches the "a[rel]" selector. How do I detect which "a[rel]" element is clicked or how do I cache the jQuery overlay that is popped up?

Comment: @Rookian - It *should* close all of them, but you could add a click handler to `a[rel]`, like this: `var overlayElem; $('a[rel]').click(function() {  overlayElem = $(this); });` then when you want to close, `overlayElem.overlay().close();`, `overlayElem` being a global variable holding the last opened overlay.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set `api:true` in properties if you want to close it from js:

```
var overlay = $("a[rel]").overlay({
    ...
    api:true
});

overlay.close();
```

Comment: Works for me. Closes overlay by class name. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The problem, in case of assigning the overlay to a class, is that there will be many overlay elements, so all must be closed:

```
$.each($(".caddy_grid"), function(i, v){$(v).overlay().close();})
```

Alternatively, it is possible to simulate a click on the close button:

The class that triggers the overlay in my case is **caddy_grid_overlay**, so the close button can be accessed as:

```
$('.caddy_grid_overlay .close').click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("a[rel]").data("overlay").close();
```

I use this to close my overlays.

source : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/having-trouble-timing-jquery-tools-overlay-to-close-after-a-few-seconds

Answer (score 2):

It will work for you, Please refer code here,

```
var api = $("a[rel]").data("overlay");

api.close();//close this overlay
```

Reference :

http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html#api

http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scripting.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    var overlayObject = $("a[rel]").overlay({ 
        top: 50,
        expose: {
                    color: '#232323',
                    closeOnClick: true
                },

                onClose:function() {   
                    $('#reg-login').hide();
                    $('#reg-register').hide();
                },
        effect: 'apple'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function and call it from anywher you want.

this function gonna work based on class name and a link.

> function closeOverlay() {
>           alert('aa'); 
>            var overlay = $(\"a.ShowOverlay\").overlay({ 
>               api:true
>           });
>
> ```
>     overlay.close();
> }
> ```